# Plot polynomial regression with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am writing a python code for investigating the over-fiting using the function  sin(2.pi.x) in range of [0,1]. I first generate N data points by adding some random noise using Gaussian distribution with mu=0 and sigma=1. I fit the model using M-th polynomial. Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# generate N random points
N=30
X= np.random.rand(N,1)
y= np.sin(np.pi*2*X)+ np.random.randn(N,1)

M=2
poly_features=PolynomialFeatures(degree=M, include_bias=False)
X_poly=poly_features.fit_transform(X) # contain original X and its new features
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_poly,y) # Fit the model

# Plot
X_plot=np.linspace(0,1,100).reshape(-1,1)
X_plot_poly=poly_features.fit_transform(X_plot)
plt.plot(X,y,"b.")
plt.plot(X_plot_poly,model.predict(X_plot_poly),'-r')
plt.show()
```

[image: Picture of polynomial regression]

I don't know why I have M=2 lines of m-th polynomial line? I think it should be 1 line regardless of M. Could you help me figure out this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your data after polynomial feature transformation  is of shape (n_samples,2).
So pyplot is plotting the predicted variable with both columns.

Change the plot code to

```
plt.plot(X_plot_poly[:,i],model.predict(X_plot_poly),'-r')
where i your column number
```

Comment: it works now. thanks you very much. To the best of my knowledge, i should be 0, right? because I would like to draw a picture according to X, not higher polynomial.

Comment: i can be 0 or 1. If you want to plot the graph with original dataset i.e. before using polynomial feature generation, then you should use variable X_plot  defined in your code  . If it solved your problem please accept the answer.

Comment: @ ashwinids: I accepted. However, when I tried with M=0, the code doesn't code. Do you know how can I handle with this problem? because I need to evaluate at M=0, too

Comment: M should be atleast 2. With M=0 you will have an empty numpy array and M=1 will return the input without change. I suggest you should read the documentation first.

Comment: @ ashwinids: Thanks very much. I know that M must be different than 0. I mean, do you know how can I fit the model with straight light with wo=const? because I cannot apply polynomial regression.